# Как использовать конструкцию declare в PHP?

Tags: php

Объясните, пожалуйста, как можно использовать с пользой для какого-либо дела конструкцию declare. В мане сказано, что его можно использовать для замера времени выполнения участков кода, и самое интересное, что якобы для организации многопоточности. Если можно, приведите примеры кода использующие эту конструкцию. Желательно для организации мультитрединга, ну и для замера времени выполнения тоже.

Comment: нету в php "мультитрединга", если бы он был, да еще и так просто организован вы бы об этом уже знали-бы. Пример для замера времени есть в интернете, достаточно всего-то вбить - **declare php**

Answer (score 2):

Здесь достаточно подробно расписано: [declare](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.declare.php).

> Конструкция declare используется для установки директив исполнения для блока кода. Синтаксис declare схож с синтаксисом других конструкций управления исполнением.

По сути вопроса интерес представляет директива tick. Смысл в том, что для каждой строки ; и блока {} получается тик, например:

```
function notifyTick() {
    print "This is tick";   
}

register_tick_function("notifyTick");
```

и пусть есть два варианта

```
declare(ticks=1) echo 'Hello!';
```

и

```
declare(ticks=1) {{ echo 'Hello!'; }}
```

тогда во втором случае тиков будет больше, чем в первом.

Тики не являются аналогом либо заменой многопоточности, как верно заметил [@AlexWindHope](/users/3545/alexwindhope).